# swift bringSubViewToFront

Tags: ios, swift, view

I have a bottomView with opacity set to 0.65, and embedded in that View I have 5 buttons -  which also gets the 0.65 opacity attribute -  but How do I make the buttons get rid of the opacity? 
I want the buttons to be very clear

I have tried to make outlets of the View and the Buttons and set the buttons to the front -  view, but it doesn't change the appearance of the button??

```
@IBOutlet weak var bottomView: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var findVejOutlet: UIButton!
@IBOutlet var superViewOutlet: UIView!

@IBAction func findVejButton(_ sender: Any) {
            superViewOutlet.bringSubview(toFront: findVejOutlet)
}
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    settingView()
}

func settingView(){
    bottomView.bringSubview(toFront: findVejOutlet)

}
```

[image]

Comment: What you are describing is iOS drawing behavior. It's not specific to Swift. You should add the iOS tag to your question.

Comment: I've added ios tag to the question -  and thanks -  I will try to modify my solution according to your suggestions

Answer (score 2):

If you set the opacity of a view to a value of less than 1, it makes *all* the contents of a view partly transparent (including subviews). You can't change that, and opacity has nothing to do with the front-to-back ordering of the views.

You either need to make the parent view fully opaque and the non-button subviews partly transparent, or remove the buttons from the translucent view and instead put them in the common parent view.